# Multiple Html.AntiForgeryToken (inside an HTML table)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, security

In my view I have a loop to render a list of users:

```
foreach (var user in Model.Users.Collection)
{}
```

One of the columns of this table is an input button, to perform some action to a specific user. The input button does a POST request to an action method.

I'd like to protect this with **Html.AntiForgeryToken**. However, each table row has an **Html.BeginForm** with an input button.

```
<td>

            <% using(Html.BeginForm(user.IsInRole ? "RemoveUserFromRole" : "AddUserToRole", "usermanagement", FormMethod.Post)) { %>                   
            <%: Html.AntiForgeryToken("AddRemoveUser") %>
            <input name="action" type="submit" value="Update" />

            <% } %> 

            </td>
```

How should I proceed about this? Render multiple Html.AntiForgeryToken one for each Html.BeginForm? Is it correct to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the same salt value for all tokens.

```
<%: Html.AntiForgeryToken("some_random_string") %>
```

and then you could try apply this same salt on the two controller actions you are posting to:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken(Salt = "some_random_string")]
```

Comment: Should you think about another solution! Now this Salt became deprecated  `'System.Web.Mvc.ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute.Salt' 
   'The 'Salt' property is deprecated. 
   To specify custom data to be embedded within the token, 
   use the static AntiForgeryConfig.AdditionalDataProvider property.'  `